# sscanf only partially reads comma-delimited list

Tags: c, scanf

I have such string in buff:

```
$GPGGA,031956,2218.2035,N,11410.7595,E,1,04,3,9,005.9,M,-001.3,M,,*51
```

What am I doing is reading some values between comas to arrays:

```
char ts[16];
char lat[16];
char latd[16];
char lon[16];
char lond[16];
char sats[16];

sscanf(
       buff,
       "%*[^,],%[^,]s,%[^,]s,%[^,]s,%[^,]s,%[^,]s,%*[^,],%[^,]s",
       ts,lat,latd,lon,lond,sats
       );
```

sscanf reads ts well (031956). However lat, latd etc. are not filled with any value.

Why it happens ?

Comment: change to `"%*[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%*[^,],%[^,]"`

Comment: Well done ! Now I get it. Seems like s is also kind of pattern... God, now I see how well sscanf is written.

Comment: Be sure to check the return value as in `if (6 == sscanf(buff, "...)) Success();` to find out if you indeed did scan the number of values sought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some erroneous `s` characters in your format string.

Your current regex matches `%*[^,],%[^,]` but then can't match the `s` character that follows and so the rest of the string doesn't match. If you remove those `s` characters then the format should match the values 031956, 2218.2035, N, 11410.7595, E, 04 in the string you supplied.